# Is it possible in typesense to search with connections?

Tags: typesense

Is it possible in typesense to make complex search requests with connections like in graphql?

As example i have a collection with customers and a collection with projects. In a search request should my client now see the name of the project and also the name and address of the customer. So is it possible that i get this informations in the same query? I mean my goal is that i can declare the customer-id in the project-document to get this data too.

Btw i know i can write in every project-document also the data from the customer but it's not so comfortable when the customer address or place will change because then i must update every project with the new customer data.

More infos:

--Schema customers

```
[{ name: 'name', type: 'string' },
 { name: 'address', type: 'string' },
 { name: 'place', type: 'string' } ...]
```

--Schema projects

```
 [{ name: 'name', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'description', type: 'string' } ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Typesense as of v0.22, so you would have to [flatten](https://typesense.org/docs/0.22.1/api/collections.html#indexing-nested-fields) the data across collections into a single collection.

But there is an open issue to track this request here: https://github.com/typesense/typesense/issues/229